# Guidelines for creating additional full-text catalogs

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, full-text-search, full-text-catalog

The nice wizards says

> If this is a large table or view, or if the chosen full-text catalog has indexed or other large tables, consider assigning this table or view its own full-text catalog

"Large" is a pretty subjective term, is it 1000 records or 1,000,000 in a table? What guidelines do you follow when creating additional full-text catalogs?  Is it worse to have 1 full-text catalog handling many tables, or a 1-1 relationship between catalog and table?  I've usually only broken them up based on specific rules, e.g. this catalog ignores any non-alphanumeric, this one allows everything, this one is accent sensitive, etc.

Comment: I assume we are talking about SQL Server 2005 here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a read at this FT  white paper published by the SQL CAT team: [SQL Server 2005 Full-Text Queries on Large Catalogs: Lessons Learned](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917695.aspx). It is more broad than your specific question, but covers the subject of FT scale and performance with some good hints.